# right floated div moving into another div on window resize

Tags: jquery, css, html

how can i stop my right floated div from overflowing into another div on it's left?

```
<div class="HeaderArea">

   <div id="centertopnav">
   </div>

   <div class="srchbox">
   </div>

</div>

#centertopnav {margin:0 auto; padding:0; width:780px;}

.srchbox { 
 float:right; 
 margin:-20px 290px 0 0 ;
}
```

HeaderArea is full body width, centertopnav is centered using margin "0px auto" and
srchbox is floated right but as i resize window, srchbox shifts into the centertopnav..

what property do I use to fix this? Overflow? clear? 
here is screeshot: http://pixholder.com/view.php?id=1160

Comment: Well, where do you want it to go instead?

Comment: Why not attach it to `centertopnav` so that the two of them are centered as one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's HeaderArea width? If it's to small srchbox will floating right but can't go any further.